# Can't load a URL in a WebView from a popover

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a favorites popover and a webView. When you select a cell in the tableview of the popover, the webview should load that URL, but I get a SIGABRT or a BAD_ACCESS.

Here's some code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (tableView == favoritesTable1) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        textField.text = cell.textLabel.text;
        [web loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:cell.textLabel.text]]];
        [cell release];
        [favoritesTable1 reloadData];
    }
}
```

I want to get something like this but full working: http://cl.ly/3O2y1S3b3d031L2C122M

PS: The popover is a new viewController from the same class where the webview is set.

Answer (score 0):

You should not initiate your data array each time you compute a cell. This seems very inefficient and error prone. The setup of the array belongs e.g. into `viewDidLoad`.

Also, look for your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method because that is where you should be trying to send the URL to the web view, not `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake posting the code. In two minutes I'll post the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.